# Attach one variable to many on click with this

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a working code like that

```
 $(document).on ("click", ".submit", function () {
    the_id = $(this).attr('data') ;
       });

 $(document).on ("mouseover", ".edit", function () {
    the_id = $(this).attr('data') ;
       });

  $(document).on ("mouseout", ".avoid", function () {
    the_id = $(this).attr('data') ;
       });
```

But it looks very annonying this variable `the_id` because I have to define it every time I have some click or mouseover , I have many of onclick onmouseover with same variable .

the problem is that I couldn't make it as Global variable because it has `$(this)` which gets the id of that clicked elements.

How can I make it like that :

```
 the_id = $(this).attr('data') ; // how to define it here with $this() <------- 
 $(document).on ("click", ".submit", function () {
   // its defined here the_id ;
       });

 $(document).on ("mouseover", ".edit", function () {
   //its defined here the_id  ;
       });

  $(document).on ("mouseout", ".avoid", function () {
    // its defined here the_id  ;
       });
```

thanks!

**EDIT**

as Ibrahim said i created a function

but im getting error that id is not function

```
   function id(){
        classList = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
        $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
       if (item.indexOf("user") > -1) {this_id = item;}
       if (item.indexOf("chatid") > -1) {this_chat_id = item;}
       });
     this_id = this_id.replace('user', '');
     this_chat_id = this_chat_id.replace('chatid', '');
  return [this_id, this_chat_id];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge those 3 lines to one, by specifying all elements separated by comma like this:

```
$(document).on ("click mouseover mouseout", ".submit, .edit, .avoid", function () {
   the_id = $(this).attr('data') ;
});
```

Or you can keep the 3 lines but call the same function:

```
function doAction() {
    the_id = $(this).attr('data');
}

$(document).on ("click", ".submit", doAction);

$(document).on ("mouseover", ".edit", doAction);

$(document).on ("mouseout", ".avoid", doAction);
```

Comment: Yes sorry i mean this edit , i really know this solution , look my edit , its not just clic

Comment: You can use the same approach for events too, but without comma. Look at my edit. :)

Comment: wont work :( . will submit how i have done when i come home

Comment: it saids doAction is not a function

Comment: Your code looks fine. If it says function is undefined then most probably the function is not visible in the scope where you try to call it.

Comment: if i call the function under my code , it says cannot call split of underfinned

Comment: ok you was right ,it was not visible i putted the function inside document ready . But now im getting `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` ! what can be the problem pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Define the variable top of the script tag open and your all the function in the script is able to use this variable. Like below

```
<script>
   var the_id = '';

   __YOUR CODE__
</script>
```